# Windows device url parts

Tags: windows, usb, webcam, url

Hy all,

What is name of this device url string? After VID and PID?

[image]

Comment: Learn more about Generic Identifiers>>>>>>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hardware-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last part see
[Microsoft Instance ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-hardware/drivers/install/instance-ids):

> An instance ID is a device identification string that distinguishes a device from other devices of the same type on a computer. An instance ID contains serial number information, if supported by the underlying bus, or some kind of location information.

You will find an excellent treaty of the subject in this
[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885175/165358).

It depends mainly upon the device and the data it furnishes, such as serial number,
whether the instance ID stays the same between plug-out/in for same or different
USB ports and same or different computers.